# Replace nth char with sed

Tags: linux, string, replace, sed

i wanna change or delete every 3rd and 4th chars of a string with sed.

For example the text:

> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxz

Should be transformed to:

> abefijmnqruv

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, but how can i do it without use a lot of dots for bigger positions, 17th and 18th for example?

Answer (score 7):

```
echo abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxz | sed 's/\(..\)../\1/g'
```

Comment: Ok, but how can i do it without use a lot of dots for bigger positions, 17th and 18th for example?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got the answer

> echo abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxz | sed 's/\(.\{4\}\).\{3\}/\1/g'

4 and 3 are examples... thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Another variation with sed

```
sed 's/\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{2\}\)/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "abcdefghijklmnopqr" | sed -n 's/\(..\)\..\([a-z][a-z]*\)/\1\2/p'
```